# Not able to show tags using /xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input.*

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-tags-input

I am trying the tagsinput plugin to work in a textarea which is inside a div that is loaded by the jquery dialog plugin call.

Plugin used is the **/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input.**

I did an initial check if the textarea element is ready. It is while before being called.

The textarea doesn't get displayed as tags by the tagsinput plugin. However when I try the same from firebug in the browser:

```
 $('#textarea').importTags('guava','cherry'); // this works
```

Code below:

jsp file:

```
<div id="mydialog">
<textarea name="tags" id="textareaId">
</div>
```

javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#mydialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    position: ['center', 'top'],
    show: 'blind',
    hide: 'blind',
    width: 400,
    dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
    buttons: {
        "YES": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

$('#textarea').tagsInput({
   'autocomplete_url': '',
   'autocomplete': { 
       source: ['apple','banana'],
       autofill:true
    },
   'height':'100px',
   'width':'300px',
   'interactive':true,
   'defaultText':'add a tag',
});
$('#textarea').importTags('guava','cherry');
});
```

Any help why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$('#textarea') was not yet ready in the document before the tagsinput was called. I delayed my invocation for tagsinput and it worked Ok.